# Laptop with 7 row keyboard layout

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I used to work with a Thinkpad t420s and t61 which both have awesome keyboards like this:

[image]

Unfortunately Lenovo replaced it by a really bad 6 row layout.

Is there any new 14' - 15'  Laptop with decent power and a similar desktop like keyboard Layout out there?

Comment: If Lenovo doesn't make one than the chances are lower than finding a trackpoint on a laptop keyboard. HP, Dell and Toshiba had models with trackpoints IIRC. I have been using T530, T560, a desktop version of the newer Lenovo layout, Chromebooks (Capslock replaced by another modifier) and desktop chiclet keyboards with different button mappings sans numblock and a mix of different layouts (QERTZ/QWERTY). I don't see what was so "awesome" about these old keyboards and nobody made an attempt to provide a sound explanation that goes beyond just inability to adapt.

Comment: Hi, the main thing for me is, that the old layout is pretty much similar to a classic desktop keyboard. So transition between my working place and the laptop is almost seamless. For example I use `Del`, `Home`, `End`, `PgUp`, `PgDn` really a lot. If you compare the old vs. the new layout you see, that the new layout hides the F and other function keys in a small bar at the top. This makes it impossible to write blind and switching from desktop to laptop will always be a pain. I don't have any issues with the chiclet keys it is just the layout.

Comment: Okay, I see my solution so far was to move to keyboard layouts where `Home`, `End`, `PgUp`, `PgDn` are mapped to the cursor keys and get used to that.

Comment: As a software partial solution I map the function keys to the other keys.  I rarely use the higher level function keys anyways.  I actually am still using the t420 to type this on so I do miss the old layout for sure.

Comment: @Finn I just found [this](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/50924.html) blog post where Matthew Garrett describes how he ported coreboot to the 51NB X210 motherboard, which is a project to retrofit current hardware into old 7 row keyboard chassis. At the moment only the X210 seems to be in stock, no T61. It will be interesting to see where this is going given that supply of old parts will run out at some point and some people are looking for USB-C support.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, ThinkPad 25 is going to have 7 row keyboard layout https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/10/lenovos-25th-anniversary-thinkpad-brings-back-the-keyboard-we-love/